# Need to calculate growth per second.

Tags: exponential-function

I start with say 5.
multiplied by 1.5 per second. How do I calculate how many seconds I need to reach say 7000?

(im trying to make a formula for a table top adventure I'm planning for the weekend)

For now im using spreadsheets with tables per second for this. Would be awesome to be able to calculate it with a formula.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Hint: population after 2 seconds: $N=5\times 1.5^2$. Set this for n seconds and use logarithms to ease the process :)

Comment: @C.Koca learning about logarithms now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start with 5.
After one second, you get $5*1.5=7,5$.
After two second you get $7.5*1.5=5*1.5*1.5=5*(1.5)^2=11.25$
...
After n seconds, you get $5*(1.5)^n$

That is, let $s_{start}$ be your starting number and $s_{final}$ your final number, $\epsilon$ the number you multiply by, and $n$ the number of iterations. Then $$ s_{final}=s_{start}*\epsilon^n $$

Therefore, $$ \frac{s_{final}}{s_{start}}=\epsilon^n $$
and finaly,
$$ log_\epsilon(\frac{s_{final}}{s_{start}})=n $$
To answer your example, $s_{final}=7000$, $s_{start}=5$, $\epsilon=1.5$, then
$$ n=17.8665 $$

Comment: do you have any idea how I syntax this in XLS?
log ? 1.5(7000/5)?

Comment: Could you please tell me what do you mean by XLS ?

Comment: was looking for a way to express it in a spreadsheet syntax. Found it.
= LOG(start/final,e)

Comment: Ok, glad you found it!

Comment: Note : I think it would be  =LOG(final/start,e)